# Generating a Pivot Table using Macros (Run-time error 1004)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a Pivot Table using a VBA Macro. I am new to VBA, and I do not have much experience. I was hoping if someone could help fix the following error: "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error".

The code is as follows:

```
 Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "data!R14C1:R271C47", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
        "Sheet23!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable12", DefaultVersion:=6
    Sheets("Sheet23").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable12").PivotFields("Process")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable12").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable12").PivotFields("Process"), "Count of Process", xlCount
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable12").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable12").PivotFields("Walkthrough/Phase 1 Scheduled Start Date"), _
        "Count of Walkthrough/Phase 1 Scheduled Start Date", xlCount
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable12").PivotFields( _
        "Count of Walkthrough/Phase 1 Scheduled Start Date")
        .Caption = "Min of Walkthrough/Phase 1 Scheduled Start Date"
        .Function = xlMin
    End With
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    Range("D3").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: What line throws the error? Note that you need the `"data!R14C1:R271C47"` to be dynamic and not hard-coded.

Comment: Hi. How would I make it dynamic? So when I debug it, the following lines are highlighted:

`
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "data!R14C1:R271C47", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
        "Sheet23!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable12", DefaultVersion:=6
`

Comment: Look at questions here on SO of how to create a pivot cache.

Comment: Is the data range always "A14:AU27" on sheet named "data"? And presumably you want the pivot table created at "A3" on the new sheet